# Sending push notifications to a non-certified Android device

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, mqtt

Since Firebase is only working with Android devices which are **certified by Google** (thus have Google services installed) I'm struggling to make push notifications work for our (non-certified) Interactive Whiteboards which run on Android. I've got a client app which so far asks the server for changes *every X secs* through [Androids internal alarm manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager).

As this is for sure not the best approach I would like to ask here for some advice/ideas on how to tackle this issue better. Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: i'm sure there are lots of other providers of push notifications, you don't have to use firebase, perhaps just find something else ?

Comment: On Android it really seems you have to go through Firebase. Pusher etc. are all working with Firebase under the hood. I guess thinking outside the box is needed here.